# Pycharm Project default interpreter does not match my Python system default installation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am a little confused about Python installations, configurations and interpreter locations.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have been using **Pycharm** for some time, installed both **Python 2.7** and **Python 3.8** (even though I am not sure *where* I installed both...).
Now I started a project with Pycharm that uses some specific packages that I included in the `requirements.txt` file. Every time I open Pycharm it asks me to install those packages (`Package requirements 'numpy~=1.16.6', 'scipy~=1.5.1' are not satisfied. Install requirements/Ignore requirements`), I do it and the next time I get the same request.

If I try to set up a Python interpreter through the GUI of Pycharm I get the following options:

```
Project Default (Python 2.7) /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7 /usr/bin/python
Python 3.8 (OldProject) ~/Workspace/OldProject/venv/bin/python
Python 3.8 (OldProject2) ~/Workspace/OldProject2/venv/bin/python
```

How can I change the system default Python to version 3.8?

If I run on the terminal:

```
python --version
```

I get

```
Python 3.8.2
```

So why is Pycharm displaying Python 2.7 as Project Default? And why there's no Python 3.8 system installation among the options?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Pycharm python interpreter by going in to File -> Settings and than search python interpreter at the search input.

The command line python version is the one that the "Path" envirment variable refer too (the file python.exe in the relevent python folder)